# Access AWS SES from a lambda function that is inside a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, amazon-ses

I have already set up the necessary VPC endpoints as stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-set-up-vpc-endpoints.html).

However, when inside of my Lambda function (using Node.js) I do:

```
const sesClient = new SESClient({ });
...
await sesClient.send(sendEmailCommand);
```

it times out after 5 minutes.

Should a specific endpoint be specified when initializing the SES Client?

Comment: Did you also allow inbound traffic to the VPC Endpoint's security group on the relevant ports from a security group assigned to the Lambda function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Allan Chua suggested, using the SES SMTP interface with a tool like [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) works.

```
nodemailer.createTransport({
  port: 587,
  host: `email-smtp.${region}.amazonaws.com`,
  auth: {
    user: smtpUsername,
    pass: smtpPassword
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the corresponding [SES API logs from CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html) to make sure that the SES API calls are going through your VPC endpoint properly. I have a strong hunch that the SDK is connecting to the API and VPC endpoints for SES are meant for SMTP. To solve your problem, please use SMTP interface or introduce a NAT Gateway to your VPC if your use-case allows it.

Comment: After some research, I assume that by SMTP interface you mean to use some library (like Nodemailer if I'm using Node.js for my lambda function). But if I'm using Cloudformation to manage my infrastructure stack, how can I generate the necessary SMTP credentials that I needed for the connection via this library?